# Shared Server not supporting gzip

Tags: iis, performance, gzip, shared-hosting, compression

I have designed a website in ASP and uploaded on readyhosting's windows shared server. I ask them to enable gzip option from IIS web server but they are no supporting.

Is there any option to compress files over network?

thanks,
Rau

Answer (score 0):

Take a look: [Compressing HTTP output with an HttpModule (C#)](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/ASP.NET/0200__File-Directory/CompressingHTTPoutputwithanHttpModuleC.htm) and [Understanding Compression and Decompression in ASP.NET 2.0](http://aspalliance.com/1348_Understanding_Compression_and_Decompression_in_ASPNET_20.all)

Answer (score 0):

The [blowery.org HttpCompressionModule](http://blowery.org/httpcompress/) was [mentioned](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000122.html) in Jeff's blog a while back when he was considering compression options.

There was also bunch of other good/related stuff he's blogged about:

> [Coding Horror - compression related articles](http://www.google.com/custom?hl=en&domains=www.codinghorror.com&q=codinghorror.com:+compress+http&btnG=Search&sitesearch=www.codinghorror.com)